# Javascript - My preview delete the file in my input

Tags: javascript, html

I had a form like this :

```html
<form action="assets/php/test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
   <div id="imgcont" hov="url('../data/img.svg')" >
      <input type="file" name="clue" value=" " id="img" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg">
   </div>
   <input type="text" name="message" id="message">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="send">
</form>
```

And I don't know why but he always return an empty Array like this :

```
Array ( [clue] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) ) 0
```

-The name of the input file is good

-Here is no other iteartion of this name in my code

I rewrite the code to delete all unusefull things

```html
<form action="assets/php/Send_Message.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <input type="file" name="clue" id="fileToUpload" value=" " id="img" accept=".png,.jpg,.jpeg" >
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message">
        <input type="submit" value="" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
        
        print_r($_POST);
        echo '</br>';
        print_r($_FILES);
    ?>
```

-The file is here because I use JS to show a preview of this image

```js
function updateImageDisplay() {

    var curFiles = input.files;
    if(curFiles.length === 0) {
        preview.style.backgroundColor = "#ff4c42";
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < curFiles.length; i++) {
        if(validFileType(curFiles[i])) {
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(curFiles[i]);
        } else {
            console.log("File Type Not Valid");
            
        }
        preview.style.backgroundImage = "url("+image.src+")"
        preview.innerHTML += '<span onclick="Reinit()" class="delete" id="cl" >X</span>' ;
        }
    }
}

var fileTypes = [
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/pjpeg',
    'image/png'
]

function validFileType(file) {
    for(var i = 0; i < fileTypes.length; i++) {
        if(file.type === fileTypes[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

the problem comes from this two lines in my js

```js
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(curFiles[i]);
```

It's like my js just take the imlage and not copying it.

Comment: `I wrote this code something like a week ago and he works well at that moment`...ok, so what did you change after that? I assume you have records in source control, or elsewhere if you made other changes to the server or environment? And why have you got `value=" "` in the HTML of the file input? It's pointless, and probably harmless, but remove it just in case. `with my other test`...what test was that? You mean the one you did a week ago? Please clarify.

Comment: P.S. The error has nothing to do with move_uploaded_file - your code isn't getting that far. I've amended the title.

Comment: yea but just in case i wrote it :D You done well. I removed the value=" " and it change nothing

Comment: `just in case i wrote it`...just in case what, exactly? Don't be a [cargo cult programmer](https://blog.ndepend.com/cargo-cult-programming/) . In other words, all your code should have a purpose. If you don't know what something is for, either go and find out, or don't include it.

Comment: Anyway if you said it worked previously, then basically you need to work out what changed between then and now. We can't help you with that since we don't know what you've changed. (On the face of it, the code you've shown looks like it would work, but perhaps something subtle is occurring. The most obvious thing is to rule out is the JS. Temporarily remove all the Javascript and try it again.)

Comment: I m talking about my tilt when i say that ...

Comment: I hadded some new prepared request

Comment: I resolve some errors in css

Comment: Neither of those sound like it would be relevant, probably - but without the specifics no-one can know for sure.

Comment: `I m talking about my tilt when i say that`...no idea what you mean by a "tilt" in this context, sorry.

Comment: title* i missed a touch

Comment: Dear in order to see the actual issue as you have not included all of the code specially fileValidator() function in PHP and also didn't explain what is the use of JS code and where it will be called, kindly either include all the useful code which is included in your script or elaborate the purpose of these unused functions.

Comment: The php is not involved in this problem, after many researches the problem would probably come from my js who takes the image to create a blob and the html can't send it anymore

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `php.ini` [directives](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` are larger than the file you are trying to upload. Also make sure that `file_uploads` isset to `1` and `max_file_uploads` to something larger than `0`.

This error may also occur if you have nested multiple forms inside each other.

Comment: I already take a look at php.ini, and it seems like it not come from there

Comment: I had two form in that page but not they are separate